# Contact information on Opportunity record

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

I'm building an integration between Salesforce and a proposal creator tool. Most of my users use the integration from opportunity object. I'm using the integration to pull opportunity data in the proposal via token. For example - `{{Name}}`, `{{Account.Name}}`, `{{CloseDate}}` etc.

However, I don't see any field on opportunity which has person details, to whom the proposal should be sent. I would expect opportunity to have a contact associated. How do Salesforce users generally do this?

I've no experience as Salesforce user or admin, so please forgive the naivety of question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need OpportunityContactRole Object records from Opportunity related List.
It represents the role that a Contact plays on an Opportunity.

> Records of this object type appear in the user interface on the
>   Opportunity Detail page. Like most other objects, records of this
>   object type have their own unique ID that you use when updating or
>   deleting records.

There is a many-to-many relationship between Opportunity and Contact, through a junction object called OpportunityContactRole. In an opportunity, you may add many opportunity contact roles. There is no restriction on Account from which the Contact can come, you can add any Contact from any Account. For example, Srinivas Balle might be the Executive Sponsor for the opportunity `Universal Container`, and Edna Frank might be the Quality Control for same Opportunity.

> In order to associate a Contact and Opportunity via UI, you can
>   navigate to the related list of opportunity and On the opportunity
>   Contact Role, then click the new button.

ContactId is the key field on OpportunityContactRole which is the id of an associated Contact.

Reference:-

1. [OpportunityContactRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm?search_text=Oppotunitycontact)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom lookup on opportunity to contact and then when creating a record for opportunity you can select the contact to whom the proposal should be sent.
[image]